# 2sxc update an entity to set IsPulished to false

Tags: 2sxc

I need to be able to set the IsPublished value of an existing entity to false through the WebAPI. According to https://2sxc.org/en/docs/feature/feature/3360 :

> Just so you don't get things wrong: an Update with "IsPublished"=false will not hide the existing entity, but will hide the change you just made.

Is there a way to do this through the WebAPI, or can this only be done through the 2sxc GUI panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v13.02 you can include IsPublished `true` or `false`. The behavior will be

- true will set everything to published
- false will set it to draft, and if there was a published one before, it will remain published

In v13.03 you will be able to do `true`, `false` and `"draft"`

- true will set everything to published
- false will set everything to unpublished
- "draft" will set the updated data to draft, and if there was a published one before, that will leave.

Answer (score 0):

It will be available in 2sxc 13.02

old answer:

---

As of now it can only be done with very internal APIs.

But I believe it would be fairly easy to add it to the simple data-api - the `App.Data.Update(...)` - so if you think it's important, just add an issue.

Comment: Update: it will be in v13.02 ;)